# Does anyone know the SMS gateway for Spectrum Mobile and can I use SMTP?

Tags: sms

Building a C# program that will send text messages to customers that opt in to getting text messages.  Does anyone know the gateway for Spectrum Mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with a customer.  I called Spectrum but was unable to get through since I am not a customer.  I had the customer on Spectrum Mobile do a test on the Verizon gateway and he had success.

From what I have read, Spectrum Mobile uses Verizon predominately and I read that they may also use Sprint towers in some regions.  I suggest you test on Verizon's gateway and it doesn't work maybe try Sprint's.

Verizon SMS: xxx-xxx-xxxx@vtext.com
Verizon MMS: xxx-xxx-xxxx@vzwpix.com
Sprint SMS: xxx-xxx-xxxx@messaging.sprintpcs.com
Sprint MMS: xxx-xxx-xxxx@pm.sprint.com

Hope that helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 11):

When I tried to obtain this info from Spectrum Mobile, their "technical" line folks said they do not support MMS --- not true! I just learned and tested these gateways for Spectrum Mobile today:

- SMS message: phonenumber@vtext.com (same as Verizon)
- MMS message: phonenumber@mypixmessages.com

MMS may be used to send long messages and/or embedded or attached photo from email, and it works just as well as Verizon's MMS for long text messages.

Comment: +1 - this should be marked as the correct answer.  The mypixmessages.com works for sending messages with embedded images to Spectrum users.  vtext.com works for messages of 160 characters or less.  The message is truncated if its longer.

Comment: Just put a +1.  Agree with John, this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just moved from Verizon Wireless to Spectrum Mobile, and was looking for the same information.  I checked:

- Sprint gateways rejected
- Verizon SMS gateway @vtext.com works
- Verizon MMS gateway @vzwpix.com DOESN'T WORK

Text only!  Very inconvenient.

I'll call them when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys... I just called Spectrum and they do not have a SMS service. So, no email to text service with them.

This is bad news for me. My GPS security uses email to send text to my phone for movement alerts. I can't get the text now. UGH.